# Google Cloud Storage: Uploaded files show up on gsutil, but not on console. Versioning is off, no lifecycle rules, storage Multi-regional

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I can't see why files I uploaded won't show on the console.

Is there any versioning or lyfecycle rules by default?

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed myself the console shows some cached results. So for me I always use gsutil for latest contents.

Comment: There is open issue on GCS/Cloud console right now.
If names of your files contains space or special character requiring urlencoding - it does not show in console but accessible/visible from gsutil. Does it looks like your case?

Comment: The folders of the hidden files have a space in their name. The folders are listed but the files inside aren't. On the parent folder the folders show as " Testing this/", but when open it the name shows as "Testing%20this". My problem may be related to the issue you mention. Thanks.

Comment: Found the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79222314